# @angular/google-maps not working in production

Tags: google-maps-api-3, production, angular-google-maps

I have an app written in angular 8. When I run locally the map is working, but when I test the same data on production it is going grey and does not work.

Local:
[Working locally map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BV8HG.png)

Production:
[Empty map in production](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21Oxw.png)

I've set no application restrictions and still, the problem exists.

@Edit 1: In the console there are no errors, but only warnings:

```
A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://google.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. 
A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. 
You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at 
https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.
```

Comment: Please check your browser console for error. If any error found just paste here.

Comment: I've added response for your question in @Edit 1.

Comment: @DariuszHarwaziński Did you try on other browsers also ? Are yous still getting the same errors?

Comment: The problem was caused by improper initialization. I was dynamically attaching the script from google. Including script in <head> solved the problem for now.